# Changing how Caliburn.micro places your usercontrol on a window

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have an app using Caliburn.micro and a custom window manager. The window manager is creating my own Base Window so I can customize the look and feel across the application.

I would like to add some controls on the window something like:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CustomContent}" />
    <StatusBar Height="20" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="Blue"/>
</DockPanel>
```

I would like to have Caliburn put the usercontrol from my ViewModel in the ContentPresenter, but Caliburn is replacing the entire content of my window.

I did this in the window:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace CaliburnCustomWindow
{
    public partial class WindowBase
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CustomContent", typeof (object), typeof (WindowBase));

        public object CustomContent
        {
            get { return GetValue(CustomContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CustomContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public WindowBase()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

And then modified my WindowManager to do this:

```
using System.Windows;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace CaliburnCustomWindow
{
    internal class AppWindowManager : WindowManager
    {
        protected override Window EnsureWindow(object model, object view, bool isDialog)
        {
            Window window = view as Window;

            if (window == null)
            {
                if (view.GetType() == typeof (MainView))
                {
                    window = new WindowBase
                    {
                        CustomContent = view,
                        SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual
                    };

                    window.Height = 500;
                    window.Width = 500;
                }

                window.SetValue(View.IsGeneratedProperty, true);
            }
            else
            {
                Window owner2 = InferOwnerOf(window);
                if (owner2 != null && isDialog)
                {
                    window.Owner = owner2;
                }
            }
            return window;
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. That binding to the CustomContent dependency property doesn't seem to work.

Is is possible to do this? If so how?

Comment: Wonder if `ContentPropertyAttribute` would work here? Maybe not, CM is probably just injecting directly into `ContentControl.Content` for your window, worth a try though maybe?

Comment: A good idea. I changed my approach and I think I'm close, but it isn't updating with the view correctly. I modified my question above to show the latest attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not either use the default `WindowManager` implementation, and pass in a new instance of a wrapper `DialogViewModel` (and create the associated `DialogView`):

```
this.WindowManager.ShowDialog(new DialogViewModel(myViewModel));
```

or abstract this code in an implementation of an `IDialogPresenter` or similar if you wanted to simplify the client code:

```
this.DialogPresenter.Show(myViewModel);
```